# This collection can't be displayed on the blade

Tags: laravel

I have function to export PDF . 
this is have more than 1 collection data on this 1 view . like this

```
 public function PDF(Request $request,$id){
    $users = User::findOrFail($id);
    $pendidikan = Data_riwayat_pendidikan::where('user_id',$id)->get();


    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.pdf',['users' => $users,'pendidikan'=>$pendidikan]);
    return $pdf->stream('Profile.pdf')->header('Content-Type','application/pdf'); 

}
```

I can displayed **USERS data** , like this **{{ $users->nama}}**

it's show normally but . I try this {{ $pendidikan->jenjang}} it's have error:

> Property [jenjang] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\resources\views\admin\pdf.blade.php)

I try dd($pendidikan); and show like this:

```
 Collection {#340 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Data_riwayat_pendidikan {#345 ▼
      #table: "data_riwayat_pendidikan"
      #guarded: []
      #connection: "mysql"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "user_id" => 14
        "jenjang" => "PERGURUAN TINGGI"
        "nama_tempat" => "Universitas blablabla"
        "jurusan" => "Rekam Medis"
        "lulus_tahun" => "2000"
        "gelar" => "gelar"
        "created_at" => "2019-07-31 08:52:30"
        "updated_at" => "2019-07-31 08:52:30"
      ]
      #original: array:9 [▶]
```

it's can showed at die dump . how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$users` is a single object. so you can access its properties like that.

But `$pendidikan` is a collection. not a single object. so you have to loop through it.

**Possible solution**

if you are doing this on a blade file.

```php
@foreach($pendidikan as $item)
    {{ $item->jenjang }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: whats differents on $users ?

Comment: `$users` is a single object.  `User::findOrFail($id)` returns a single object. but `get()` returns a collection of objects. So imagine if you want a single `pendidikan`. you need to call `Data_riwayat_pendidikan::where('user_id',$id)->first()` instead of `get()`.

Comment: i try with first , lets wait

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
@if(isset($pendidikan))
<script>
  var dataJson = JSON.parse("{!!$pendidikan!!}");
</script>
@endif
```

or

{!!$ pendidikan-> jenjang!!}

[laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade)

Displaying Unescaped Data
By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

Hello, {!! $name !!}.
Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. Always use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.